# reading hexadecimal from binary file

Tags: c, hex, extract, fread, seek

i have been constantly looking for an appropriate answer that would give me the "ahha" moment, but could not find one yet, but i have a binary file in which many other files are in, these files have hexadecimal references to the location to where the file is. 
 Say for instance, if i open up a hex editor and look at this binary file at offset 0x500, then from 0x500 to 0x507 would be the postition of that particular file within the binary file. then from 0x508 to 0x50F would be the actual file size (or block size, or chunk size or whatever you want to call it) and then the next 32 bytes is the actual file name.
Here is the C script, i know its wrong and thats why i am here asking for help to get me going :p

```
int main (){

FILE* in = fopen("file", "rb");

        int location[0x08];
        int size[0x08];
        int name[0x20];
        int fileLocation;
        int fileSize;
        int fileName;

        int buffer[0x08];
        int entryCount;

        fseek(in, 0x08, SEEK_SET);
        entryCount = fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, in);


        for ( int x = 0; x < 25; ++x) {

            fileLocation = fread(location, sizeof(location), 1, in);
            fileSize = fread(size, sizeof(size), 1, in);
            fileName = fread(name, sizeof(name), 1, in);
            // extract data based on references//


    }
}
```

I made a script in perl that does this great, but trying to migrate it to C and it is a little bit confusing to me ;0 
any help on how i could possibly migrate this to C would be very helpful, thanks for looking
here is the script in perl:

```
my $fileLocation = '';
my $fileSize     = '';
my $fileName     = '';
my $file         = '';
my $chunk        = '';
my $exit         = '';

seek( $infile, 0x10, 0 ) or die "cannot seek $infile: $!";



until ($exit) {
    read( $infile, $fileLocation, 0x08 );
    read( $infile, $fileSize,     0x08 );
    read( $infile, $fileName,     0x20 );

    if ( $fileLocation =~ 'terminating reference' ) {
        last;
    }

    $fileLocation =~    s/(.)/sprintf("%02x",ord($1))/egs;
    $fileSize =~        s/(.)/sprintf("%02x",ord($1))/egs;
    $fileName =~        s/\0+$//;

    if ( $fileLocation =~ 'terminating reference' ) {
        last;
    }

    open( $file, '>', "extracted/$fileName" ) or die "Cannot open $fileName $!";
    binmode($file);
    sysseek( $infile, hex($fileLocation), 0 );
    sysread( $infile, $chunk, hex($fileSize) );
    syswrite( $file, $chunk );

    $fileLocation = '';
    $fileSize     = '';
};
```

this will read 8 bytes then 8 more bytes then 32 bytes ad then it will extract the data based of the variables $fileLocation, $fileSize, and $filename over and over until i come to the terminating reference, then will exit

Comment: What is the specific problem here?

Comment: im trying to migrate this perl script to C, and use the same logic. i am having a hard time parsing binary files using hexadecimal offsets/references

Comment: What C code do you have so far?

Comment: updated original question with my non working script. please dont laugh me out of here lol ;p

Comment: i havent got to the extracting part because i cannot even get it to seek and read correctly

Comment: i am sure i got the whole concept of the buffers incorrect, as i dont think you can assign a hexadecimal reference inside "int location[0x08]" i dont think? like i said i couldnt find any good references on any of this

Comment: any help would be greatly appreciated as i am stuck in my track, if i can be more thourough on how the perl code work, just let me know

Comment: im really not even sure if i am using the types right as hexadecimal contains letters and numbers, and i do not think ints can have letters

Comment: If indeed "these files have hexadecimal references" then you forget the step to convert from a string *containing* hex to a number that can be used in `fseek`. To convert from a hex string to a number, you first need to make sure the data read with `fread` is a valid C string: read into a larger buffer, and add a 0 at the end.

Comment: yes if you open the binary file in hex editor like HxD, there is references to the data in hexadecimal representation like 0x2F 0x2A, then you would use those hexadecimal references to seek or fseek to the 2F 2A position then extract the data based of the hexadecimal references fileSize and fileName (though fileName is gonna be in plaintext (not hexadecimal));

Comment: Hold on, there seems to be some basic misunderstanding here. "These files have hexadecimal references" -- are you confusing the *hexadecimal* output of your hex viewer with what is actually in the file -- *binary* numbers? If so, I will remove my answer.

Comment: no if you open this file in any hex editor, HxD for example, these references are definetly in hexadecimal, as they are on the left side in HxD eg 0xDE 0xAD 0xFA 0xCE and then on the right side is ANSI characters

Comment: That answers my question. FYI, the answer is not "no", it is "yes" -- you *are* confusing binary and its representation in a hex viewer. If the file offsets were stored in hex, you'd see `30 38 43 30` at one side and `08C0` in the "ANSI" view.

Comment: if i open up hxd, and type in on the hex side 30 38 43 30 i do get 08C0 on the "ANSI" side, thats what im trying to say, the file i am working with contains all the files, each file to be extracted is a binary file, but it was compiled with a certain toolchain, which gives the files a "TOC" if you will in this main file, and in this table of contents, it references to the files, which are indeed in hexadecimal on the left side, and the filename is plaintext on the "ANSI" side (right).

Comment: let me add this. if the hexadecimal reference is fileLocation 00 00 00 00 00 02 C7 A0 (on the hexadecimal side),  and fileSize 00 00 00 00 00 03 80 00 you would seek to 0x02C7A0 then read 0x038000, then extract that data and give the fileName (which is the next 32 bytes) to the file from the ANSI side

Answer (score 2):

Since the data is stored inside the file in *hexadecimal characters*, you (1) need to read `char`s, not `int`s (thanks @user3121023), (2) convert hex to integer, then (3) use the resulting value.

Also, the return result of `fread` is *not* what you think it is! It returns the number of bytes read, and so you can check if the operation was successful.

`read_buffer` needs to be your maximum read length (32 bytes) *plus* 1 for a terminating 0. (Granted: only necessary if you want to `printf` the read data. But it's sensible to print the data, to make sure you are doing everything right.)

```
char read_buffer[0x21];

for ( int x = 0; x < 25; ++x)
{
     if (fread (read_buffer, 1,8, in) < 8) break;
     read_buffer[8] = 0;
     fileLocation = strtol(read_buffer, NULL, 16);
     printf ("location: %s -> %08Xh\n", read_buffer, fileLocation);

     if (fread (read_buffer, 1,8, in) < 8) break;
     read_buffer[8] = 0;
     fileSize = strtol(read_buffer, NULL, 16);
     printf ("size: %s -> %08Xh\n", read_buffer, fileSize);

     if (fread (read_buffer, 1,0x20, in) < 0x20) break;
     read_buffer[0x20] = 0;
     printf ("name: %s\n", read_buffer);
     // extract data based on references//
}
```

I omitted the step of copying `read_buffer` into `name`, because for this your `name` declaration is too small. Since you want `name` as a C-string (regardless of how it is saved in the original file), you need to declare it as at least

```
char name[21];
```

Comment: thank you i will check this out and yes, i was trying to printf the results because like you said it is very useful to do that to make sure i am getting the right data, but my script kept getting different printf results and never the anticipated data. i will check this out in a little while as i got busy atm. i will def report back and thanks to everyone for your help

Comment: Based on your latest comment, I infer you *cannot* use this code to do what you want.

Comment: if i can be any more thorough in my explanations please just let me know

Answer (score 1):

I think you could declare your variables on a 32 bit system as

```
unsigned long location;
unsigned long size;
unsigned long entry;
char name[0x20];
```

on a 64 bit system you would use `unsigned int` instead of `unsigned long`

then read the data

```
fseek(in, 0x08, SEEK_SET);
entryCount = fread(entry, sizeof(entry), 1, in);
printf ( "entry %lu\n", entry);

for ( int x = 0; x < 25; ++x) {

    fileLocation = fread(&location, sizeof(location), 1, in);
    printf ( "location %lu\n", location);
    fileSize = fread(&size, sizeof(size), 1, in);
    printf ( "size %lu\n", size);
    fileName = fread(name, sizeof(name), 1, in);
    printf ( "name %s\n", name);
    // extract data based on references//
}
```

Comment: thank you for the example, i will be sitting down after a while and mulling over everyones examples, and thanks again for your input